# Remove a member from workspace using bitbucket api

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I want to remove a member from my workspace using bitbucket api. I am not able to find solution can anyone help me. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs you'll use depend on if you're using Bitbucket Server / Data Center (run on-premise on your own server) or if you're on Bitbucket Cloud (the address is bitbucket.org).

Bitbucket has 2 API versions till date , v1 is deprecated.

If you are using Bitbucket Server / Data Center , you could go through the [v1 docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.6.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idp285)

And in v2 , There are multiple API's to query user permissions, webhooks that he/she is using  etc .
But there is no API that could trigger a deletion of a user account in Bitbucket cloud

Following are the two docs dealing with user API's

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/user
https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/users

Hope this clarified your query.

Thank You

Comment: v1 would work if its on-premise bitbucket server , if your repo url starts with bitbucket.org , v1 wont work

Comment: My repo url starts with bitbucket.org. So It won't work for me. I also tried in docs of bitbucket but didn't find any way of doing it. Thanks.